# Create an object from within a script Ruby

Tags: ruby, class, object

I am attemping to create an object from a class. But the objects will be created when they are needed.. Code below a bit hard to explain

```
incoming_message = #message sent though inter webs
class Repeater
    def initialize(username, ip) 
    #repeat incoming message to back to ip
    end
end
incoming_message = Repeater.new(user, ip)
```

Now I can't do that Becuase incoming_message is not a constant.
How would I get around this?

EDIT:

To clear things up a bit. I do need to use this class to create multiple objects with diffrent names. The repeater is for a chat server where an incoming message from 1 user is taken in then sent back out all of the clients connected. Each new client that connects would have a object created with that specific IP address so that messages from others can be send to the client.

It would take in messages from the other users by everyone sending to the server on the same port read the message then write to clients what it received...

I hope this helped sorry for all the confusion :)

Comment: I think you're going to have to clarify your question a bit :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain some kind of global class-level state, you should define a class-level accessor on `Repeater` that you can assign your repeating message to.

```
class Repeater
  class << self
    attr_accessor :incoming_message
  end

  def initialize(username, ip) 
    # repeat Repeater.incoming_message to back to ip
  end
end

Repeater.incoming_message = "what"
Repeater.new(user, ip)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some parsing + serialization . Can they wire an already serialized/marshalled string?

```
1) convert the ruby code to yaml or json
2) use the json or yaml load method like myobj = YAML.load(new_yaml_string)
```

or

```
save it in another file called input and do a 
require 'input'
create object of repeater
```